LWC refreshGraphQL not working properly
I have following code
  @wire(graphql, {query: '$getGraphQlQuery'})
  wiredRecords(result) {
    if (result.errors) console.error(result.errors);
    if (!result.data) return;

    this.recordsQlResult = result;
    this.records = GraphQlService.toPlainObject(result.data, this.objectName);
  }

and function which should reinvoke graphQL
  @api
  async refresh() {
    await refreshGraphQL(this.recordsQlResult)
  }

But after invoke wire not reinvoked and data not refreshed. Any ideas?
upd: as I see via Chrome Dev console refreshGraphQL getting new data, but not invoking wire again

Just throwing this out since I have not used these modules before but do you have all three of these imported: import { gql, graphql, refreshGraphQL } from "lightning/uiGraphQLApi";? How does refresh get called?

Hi - if you've solved this yourself it's best to post your own answer - that's totally find and you can accept it!

I found reason. When you using dynamic build of query like
get getQuery() {
  return gql`
    ...
     node {
       ${getFields}
     }
    ...
  `
{


getFields get fields calculating once during first request. If you will use ${'Id'} also will not refresh.

For first time it's working, but refresh will not work (request sending, but wire will not invoked)
